# Existence of Identically-2-colored Equidistant Points on the Integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, ramsey-theory

I was wondering if every 2-coloring of the integer set would result in some number of equidistant (equally-spaced) points. I proved that there will always be 3 equally-spaced points of the same color, and I wonder if I could locate a bound for the largest number of equidistant points I could find. (If it exists, of course.)

I tried induction, but it does not seem to work when parity comes in place.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: by "equally-spaced" I meant occurring in an arithmetic sequence. An equivalent form of the question is: if we partition the integer set into two sets, do we always get an $n$-term arithmetic sequence whose terms belong to exactly one of the sets? I already showed that we do when $n=3$, and I hope to further generalize it to larger $n$.

Comment: What do you call equally spaced points? Pairs of points $(x_i, y_i)$ with $y_i-x_i$ constant and all the $x_i$ and $y_i$ of the same color ? The same but with only $x_i$ of the same color than $y_i$, but color of $x_i$ can differ from $x_j$ when $i\neq j$? something else ?

Comment: If you draw a graph with as edges all the pairs $\{x_i, y_i\}$ such that $|y_i-x_i|\leq 2$, you get an infinite graph with infinitely many triangles, and in particular an infinite family of edge-disjoint triangles. Each triangle must contain a monocolored edge, so infinitely many edges are colored. By pigeonhole, there are either infinitely many monocolored pairs distant of $1$ or infinitely many monocolored pairs distant of $2$. Again by pigeonhole, there are infinitely many equidistant monocolored pairs of one specific color.

Comment: To be snarkier than caduk: The entire set of integers is equally spaced, so of course there are not only $3$, but infinitely many infinitely spaced points. Now if you has somehow tied the spacing to the colors, there might be an interesting question here. But you didn't.

Comment: @caduk I meant an n-term arithmetic sequence. Will there always be an arithmetic sequence of n terms with all elements having the same color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from [Szemerédi's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem), I believe. Let $C_i$ denote the vertices with colour $i$ for $i=1,2$. Since these sets partition $\mathbb{N} \subseteq 
\mathbb{Z}$, at least one of them has positive upper density. Therefore, by Szemerédi, at least one of the sets contains a $k$-term arithmetic progression for every $k$.

Comment: It is also an interesting question to wonder if  one of the $C_i$ necessarily contains an infinite arithmetic sequence, since the partition condition is much stronger than the hypothesis of Szemerédi's theorem. However, this is false. Consider $C_1 = \pm\bigcup_n \{n!, (n! +1), ..., (n! +n)\}$.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: @mathy_mathema No problem :)